# jdoc not rendering

Tags: joomla

I hope you can help.

I've a Joomla 2.5 site with an existing (and working) set of modules which are all showing up on the main site just fine.

For a whole myriad of reasons I've put together a custom Joomla template ... here is the out put: http://www.fabulous-women.co.uk/testing.html

in the "headerslice" position I've copied the working modules and set them to the headerslice position. However, it refuses to display.

```
     <?php if ($this->countModules('headerslice' )) : ?>
          <div id="headerslice">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name='headerslice'/>
          </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

The if statement does render the  tags... but no content. The jdoc:include type="header" renders perfectly in the  tags.

Help!

TIA

Answer (score 3):

You need a space before the closing slash of the jdoc statement.

Try:

`<jdoc:include type="modules" name='headerslice' />`

Comment: This worked for me. It should be added that neither XML nor HTML require this space, and adding a space only became a strong convention after a specific version of Netscape Navigator 4 had a bug parsing empty tags without a space before the slash. Fun times.